# How to check for open dialogs?

Tags: android, progressdialog

Assuming that I lost a reference to a dialog, how do I check for open dialogs? How can I close all open dialogs at once without knowing what dialog it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In those cases it is recommended that you open your dialogs using the method [`showDialog(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int%29). That way, even if you do not have a reference to the dialogs you can use [`dismissDialog(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dismissDialog%28int%29) to close them. Make sure to surround the `dismissDialog` call with a `try-catch` if you are not sure whether or not the dialog is open.

Comment: Thanks! I'm worrying because closing a dialog which is not open will throw an exception but yes, the try-catch block will solve my problem. I totally forgot about it. But by any chance, is there a way to know if a dialog is open?

Comment: To know that you have to keep a reference to the dialog and use methods like `isShowing`